# Get IWebDriver from setupfixture

Tags: c#, selenium

First sorry about my English. 
Here is my problem: 
I make a test for mantisbt with many test cases(report issue), so i put the login in `[SetUpFixture]` and in `[TestFixture]` `[Test, TestCaseSource("function")]` I don't know how to get driver which i use for creating chrome browser to get elements. 
Here is my code:

```
namespace testcailz
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class TestsSetupClass
    {
        public void login(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
            username.SendKeys("1353049");
            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            password.SendKeys("123456");
            IWebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Login'][@class='button']"));
            login.Click();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void GlobalSetup()
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
               driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.cs.hcmus.edu.vn/mantisbt/login_page.php");
            login(driver);
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void GlobalTeardown()
        {
            // Do logout here
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        private static int[] data()
        {
            return new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
        }

        [Test, TestCaseSource("data")]
        public void TestCaiLz(int i)
        {

            //wanna click to report new issue but how to get driver for Findelement
            Assert.AreEqual(i, i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How about *IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();* ?

Comment: I want to run all test cases in 1 Chrome.exe

Comment: Create a separate class to wrap the instance of Chrome driver. And use the same everywhere in the tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per java prospective, create driver object globally in class may be TestsSetupClass

```
 public static WebDriver driver;

@BeforeSuite
public void startUp(){

    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    login(driver);
}
```

If you what to use this driver in another classes then extends this class. like below in java

```
 public class Home extends Setup{ //...
 }
```

Thank You,
Murali